# PowerShell Where-object multiple conditions - which value matched

Tags: powershell

I am checking cluster dependencies to ensure that after adding disks to the cluster that they are correctly added to the dependencies.

I have a where statement with multiple -or statements that returns a long system.string object with all dependencies listed. How do I know or how can I check which was matched?

My statement is something like:

```
$Dependencies | where-object {$_.Dependency -like "*$CLUDisk1*" -or $_.Dependency -like "*$CLUDisk2*" -or $_.Dependency -like "*$CLUDisk2*"}
```

I know I could break this up into multiple where-objects and individually check each one, but seems like there should be a more efficient way to know which one matched my statement.

Thanks

Comment: There isn't. `-or` is a boolean operator, it doesn't transmit any information beyond "one of these were truth'y". Why is it important to know which one it matched on? What if it matches _multiple_ conditions, what would you like the script to tell you then?

Comment: Guess you can always use a `switch` statement in a loop, but you may also be able to use `-Match` foreach pattern?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen that's what I was thinking, just wanted to make sure that data wasn't retrievable in some way. Its important because I would use that data further down in the script.  If it matches multiple conditions I would like to know that as well, it would mean there is likely a configuration or naming issue. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, I will give those suggestions some thought and test.

Comment: @Jakecarter it sounds like you've already derailed yourself a bit by constructing "a long system.string object with all dependencies listed" - where did the information about those dependencies come from in the first place? Why are you storing the information in a single string? Perhaps it'd be better to just inspect the dependencies one by one, and process/mitigate anything that's missing or didn't work? Please provide the full script/context if possible :)

Comment: The long system.string comes from this line $Dependencies = Get-Cluster -name Server1 | Get-ClusterResource | Get-ClusterResourceDependency | where {$_.Resource -eq "Appname"}